Understanding an elementary set theory proof (Halmos again)
In Section (chapter) 4, Halmos encourages the reader to prove several elementary theorems including:
$$A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset $$ from the definition of union and the axioms of extensionality and specification. Similar proofs for union.
In my proof attempt (which I “checked” against what ChatGPT or CoPilot could deliver)  I wrote this:
Given (set) A (*).
$$A \cap \emptyset = \{ x : x \in A \text{ and }x \in  \emptyset\}$$
Trying to understand  $$x \in A\text{ and }x \in  \emptyset$$
I read that as having the form $$ P(x)\text{ and } Q(x)$$
So P(x) and Q(x) must be (quantified) logical statements with individual values true or false depending on x. That is what prompted question here  Is $\{x:x \in A\} = A$ a definition or a theorem? (Halmos, Naive set theory)
So is $$\{x:x \in A \text{ and }x \in  \emptyset\}$$
the same as
$\{x:x \in A \text{ and  }\textit{ false }(**) $ ?
then I get a bit lost. Is the following valid? (I don’t feel it is correct)
(**) becomes: $\{x: \text{true and false}\}$ (from *)
Leading to : $\{x: \text{false} \} = \emptyset$
The last few lines feel like a massive fudge, to be honest.
Do I need to abandon trying to understand these proofs in terms of true and false?

And the bottom of page 14 $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$. The theorems he lists are "symmetrical". Initially I "crossed the streams" - is that misdemeanour still present in my post?

Ooops! I see. Correction coming

So I don't replace $x \in A$ with true or false - it could be either because it is quantified? And that's why $x \in A$ or $F$ IFF $x \in A $. I always thought I was missing something using quantified statements in proofs - maybe the clouds are lifting.

@MauroALLEGRANZA "The intersection of a set whatever with the empty set will be the empty set ALWAYS."  I read the question and that being precisely what we are trying to prove.  We can't prove something by saying it is true and not explaining why we told it was true.

Hmm.  IMO the reasoning ${x: x\in A\ and\ FALSE}={x: FALSE}$ is valid but maybe an abuse of terminology.  "FALSE" hardly seems like a legitimate statement (it has no "verb" and the "subject", $x$, is not incorporated.  I'm not sure how to incorporate this into the proper "language" but if you know how to write "$\emptyset = {}=$ a set with no elements" properly (I don't know how) then you can write "$A\cap \emptyset=$ the set were every element is both in $A$ and doesn't exist" in probably a very similar way.

... or one can pass the buck and beg the question.  $\emptyset \subset X$ for all sets $X$ is standard thereom provable by vacuous reasoning.  And $X\cap Y\subset Y$ follows directly by definitions.  So $\emptyset \subset \emptyset \cap A$ and $\emptyset \cap  A\subset\emptyset$ so.....

@DanChristensen You can construct intersections without first constructing unions, because $A\cap B={x\in A:x\in B}$

@MauroALLEGRANZA I was responding to your comment "The intersection of a set whatever with the empty set will be the empty set ALWAYS" To my mind this is like commenting on "How do I prove the square of an even number is divisible by $4$?" with "When an even number is squared the result is ALWAYS divisible by $4$".  But you are correct the answer is obvious and you did give the argument in you answer.  But your comment... seemed strange to me as its just restating what the OP was asked to prove.

The more I think of it, The less I see anything wrong with $A\cap\emptyset={x: x\in A\text{ and }x\in \emptyset}={x:$The statements $x\in A$ and $x\in \emptyset$ are both true$}={x: x\in A$ and a false statement is true$}={x:$ a false statement is true$}= \emptyset$.  Maybe it seems weird to say $\emptyset={x:FALSE}$ but there must be someway to say $\emptyset={x: x$ doesn't exist$}$ and I see no reason why ${x:FALSE}$ wouldn't be a way to do it.

@fleablood, "FALSE" is not part of a First Order Language, and so cannot be stated within a first order theory like set theory. { x | φ(x) } = y is a shorthand for ∀x(x∈y ↔ φ(x)) where φ(x) is a well-formed formula of the Language of Set Theory. "False" is not a defined notion in set theory. Formula quantify over sets, what set is in "False".  A correct way to write the emptyset is like this: ∀x(x∈∅ ↔ x ≠ x ) OR, ∅ = { x | x ≠x } It's not just that it is weird, it is an abuse of notation. Although, the thinking is human thinking behind it, does mirror the thinking of the correct formal proof

Set Theory is a First Order Predicate Logic. Things like "false, true" are features of propositional logic

In Predicate Logic, you instead have notions of Satisfaction and Provability, rather than true/false

@MichaelCarey I feel that the OP's proof suffers the same confusion as in this deleted answer.

@MichaelCarey did you select $x\ne x$ because it was a convenient false statement (could you have used, say $2=3$, instead); or is that the actual definition of the empty set-- "the empty set is the set of all elements that are not equal to themselves"?  My point of my comment was merely the logic of the OPs statement was spot on and if it "felt weird" its in the mechanical construction which I really do not know much about.  But that there must be some equivalent correct way to say ${x:FALSE}$ and whatever it is (I don't know what is is) will make the argument sound.

@fleablood  We could in principle, define it using any property which never holds. But, The choice of (x ≠ x ) is not entirely arbitrary. In Set Theory, With just the Axiom of Extentionality, and Axiom of Set Existence- it's not clear what else one would choose. The number's 2 and 3 may not exist in such a framework. But yes, any other property which is false for every set would also work. The empty set, defined in this way, exists in very simple set theories. Another possible definition, is to say that a set is an element of the emptyset iff the set is the Russell Class.

@fleablood I 100% agree with you, the OP's informal reasoning is exactly correct, they are thinking about it in the right way.

The OP's informal reasoning is not exactly correct: $x \in A$ is not identically true.  See my answer for a full and precise explanation.

I didn't check Halmos book, but I think you write it wrong in the question.
You must have that
$$A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$$
and
$$A \cup \emptyset = A$$
this means
$$A \cup \emptyset = \{x\in X : x\in A \text{ or } x\in \emptyset\}$$
as $x\notin \emptyset$ for any $x$ this must be $A$. In a similar way you can check:
$$A \cap \emptyset = \{x\in X : x\in A \text{ and } x\in \emptyset\}$$
again as $x\notin \emptyset$ for any $x$ the only option is that this be $\emptyset$.

I made an error in my original post which is now corrected. Thanks.

The intersection of a set $A$ whatever with the empty set will always be the empty set.
The union of a set $A$ whatever with the empty set will always be the set $A$.
The arguments work this way: $x \in A \text { or } x \in \emptyset$ IFF $x \in A \text { or False } IFF x \in A$.
And similarly: $x \in A \text { and False }$ IFF $\text { False }$ IFF $x \in \emptyset$.
The conclusions follow using Extensionality.

Your proof seems hard to follow, especially the last few lines.
Your thinking seems fine, but the notation is nonstandard, and things like "becomes" are fuzzy and suspect for learners to be using.
I'll give three proofs, each using a different standard method.
Method 1: To prove that two sets are equal, it is sufficient to show that they are subsets of each other.
Remark: If you have doubts about the claim that two sets are equal iff they are subsets of each other, it is a good exercise to prove it.
The proof is a direct result of the Axiom of Extensionality. (If two sets have the same elements, then they are equal.)

Definition: subset

$x \subseteq y$ is shorthand for $\forall z \, (z \in x \to z \in y)$.

We will show two facts:
$\text{a})$ $(A \cap \emptyset) \subseteq \emptyset$
$\text{b})$ $\emptyset \subseteq (A \cap \emptyset)$

Proof of $\text{a})$

We show that $\forall z \, (z \in (A \cap \emptyset) \to z \in \subseteq)$.

To prove a universal quantification, we fix an arbitrary element - and prove the result for that set.

Fix an arbitrary set $z$.

Case $1$: $z \in (A \cap \emptyset)$ is false.

Then $$z \in (A \cap \emptyset) \to z \in \emptyset \quad \text{is true},$$ as the premise is false.

Case 2: $z \in (A \cap \emptyset)$ is true

As $z \in \emptyset \leftrightarrow z \neq z$ (per the definition of the empty set).

We have that $z \in \emptyset$ is false.

So we have that
$$z \in (A \cap \emptyset) \to z \in \emptyset \quad \text{is true},$$ as the conclusion is false.

As $z$ was arbitrarily chosen we have that $\forall z \, (z \in (A \cap \emptyset) \to z \in \emptyset)$.

Thus, $$A \cap \emptyset \subseteq \emptyset. \qquad \qquad \square$$

Remark: We often omit writing Case $1$ in proofs since the implication holds vacuously.

Proof of $\text{b}$)

We show that $\forall z \, (z \in \emptyset \to  A \cap \emptyset)$.

Fix an arbitrary set $z$.

Case $1$: $z \in \emptyset$ is false

Similar to above, z∈∅ → z∈(A ∩ ∅) is true as the premise is false

Case 2: $z \in \emptyset$ is true

As $z \in \emptyset \leftrightarrow z \neq z$, we have that $z \neq z.$
$\perp$ Contradiction. So, Case $2$ cannot happen.

As $z$ was arbitrarily chosen, we have that

$$\forall z(z \in \emptyset \to  A \cap \emptyset).$$

Thus $$\emptyset \subseteq A \cap \emptyset. \qquad \qquad \square$$

Remark: Part $\text{b}$) easily follows from the fact that the empty set is a subset of every set. If you have not seen the proof of that result, you should try to prove it yourself.
And so, as both $\text{a}$) and $\text{b}$) hold, we have that
$$A \cap \emptyset =  \emptyset.$$
Method 2: We can demonstrate an equality between sets by showing that the two sets are defined in logically equivalent ways.
This method is what I believe you were trying to do.
We prove that
$$A \cap \emptyset = \{ z \mid  z \in A \quad \text{and} \quad z \in \emptyset \} = \emptyset = \{ z \mid z \neq z \}.$$
We have the following:
Let $z$ be arbitrarily chosen.
$$z \in A \wedge z \in \emptyset \to z \in \emptyset$$ (as a conjunction always implies each of its conjuncts).
Also, we have that
$$z \in \emptyset \to z \in A \wedge z \in \emptyset$$ (a false premise implies anything).
Thus,
$$(z \in A \wedge z \in \emptyset) \leftrightarrow z \in \emptyset.$$
So,
$$\begin{align}
A \cap \emptyset &= \{ z \mid z \in A \qquad \text{and} \qquad z \in \emptyset \} \\
&= \{ z \mid z \in \emptyset \} \\
&= \{ z \mid z \neq z \} \\ 
&= \emptyset.
\end{align}$$
Key Idea: if we have two sets $$X = \{ x \mid \phi(x) \} \qquad \text{and} \qquad Y = \{ y \mid \psi(y) \},$$
if we can show that $\forall z(\phi(z) \leftrightarrow \psi(z))$, then $X = Y$, i.e. if the formula which defines two sets is logically equivalent, the two sets must be equivalent.
Method 3: Proof by Contradiction.
Assume that $A \cap \emptyset$ is not empty and derive a contradiction.
(RAA) - Assume that $A \cap \emptyset$ is not empty.
Then, $A \cap \emptyset$ contains at least one element.
Let $z \in (A \cap \emptyset)$.
By definition of set intersection, $z \in A$ and $z \in \emptyset$
So, $$z \in \emptyset.$$
By definition of the empty set:
$$z \neq z.$$
$\perp$  Contradiction.
Thus, $$A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset.$$

I haven't read Halmos so I do not know how He does it, but here is some general advice:
Your usage of $\mathsf{true}$ and $\mathsf{false}$ per se is not a problem: any predicate that is identically true, resp. false, would do, in fact it needn't even depend on $x$, $\mathsf{true}$ and $\mathsf{false}$ are already fine: keep also in mind that predicate logic is a "superset" of propositional.
But if $\mathsf{true}$ and $\mathsf{false}$ (defined constants) are really unavailable, you could just use $x \neq x$ in place of $\mathsf{false}$, which is identically false (i.e. for all $x$) and goes with the definition/equality $\emptyset = \{ x : x \neq x \}$.
That said, your proof is essentially correct, except where you replace $x \in A$ with $\mathsf{true}$ which is not valid, since $x \in A$ is not identically true, it only holds for those $x$'s that are in fact elements of $A$:
$$A \cap \emptyset = \{ x : x \in A \land x \in \emptyset \}$$
$$A \cap \emptyset = \{ x : x \in A \land \mathsf{false} \}$$
$$A \cap \emptyset = \{ x : \mathsf{false} \}$$
$$A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$$

Well, hope that helps...

Okay, I haven't read Halmos but I looked at Naive Set Theories wikipedia page.
His first axiom of extension states that two sets are equal if the have the same elements.  That means that every set that has no elements matter how the set is defined is equal to any "other" set with no elements no matter how it is defined.  We call that set (if any one such exists) the empty set.
The second axiom of Specification is that for any statement $S(x)$ and any "master" set $M$ then there is a set $\{x\in M| S(x)\}$.  This means that if $S(x)$ is any statement that is always false that $\{x\in M|S(x)\}$ is a valid set. As $S(x)$ is always false, that set has no elements and is thus equal to the empty set.
And as always false statements can always exist (for example $S(x)$ being "$x\ne x$" is always false.)  Then if any set $M$ exists then $\{x\in M|S(x)\}$ is a set with no elements and it exists and is equal to any "other" set with no elements and is the empty set.... That is, if we assume any sets exist at all.  Which leads to the third axiom ...
Now defining $M\cap N$ as $\{x \in M\cup N$ (which exists by the axiom of Unions[*])$|x\in M$ and $x\in N\}$ is utterly valid as $S(x) = [x\in M$ and $x\in N]$ is perfectly valid statement.
So $A\cap \emptyset = \{x| x\in A $ and $x\in \emptyset\}$ is the set of all elements where the statement $S(x) = [x\in A $ and $x\in \emptyset]$.  As $S(x) = P(x)\land R(x)$ where $P(x)=x\in A$ and $R(x)\in \emptyset$ and $R(x)$ is always false then $S(x)$ is always false. And $A\cap \emptyset$ is a set with no elements.
And as stated in my second paragraph all sets with no elements are equal.
Now perhaps saying $R(x)= FALSE$ is not valid but saying $R(x) = x\in \emptyset$ and $R(x)$ is always false, certainly is.
POSTSCRIPT  I suppose a really terse way of doing this might be to state: If $R(x)$ is any statement that is always false, $\emptyset=\{x|R(x)\}$.  If $R(x) := x\in A$ and $x\in \emptyset$ then $R(x)$ is always false.  So $\emptyset=\{x|R(x)\} = \{x|x\in A \land x\in \emptyset\} = A\cap \emptyset$.
===
[*] I'm not at all sure this is how Holmas defined intersection.  But in reading the axiom of specification it seems if we say $K = \{x|S(x)\}$ it is implied that there must be some tacit but unexpressed universal set $U$ and we actually mean $\{x\in U| S(x)\}$.  If in defining $A\cap B$ where $A$ and $B$ might be any arbitrary set the only way I think we can assume what the proper universal set could possibly be, I, fleablood, can only think of $A\cup B$ as a necessary and sufficient universal set.  If Holmas did it some entirely different way, than I am wrong.

A really terse way, not to mention fully correct, is how I put it: see my answer.
